# enable logging for ECS services and task definitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I have deployed GTM server side following this guide: https://aws-solutions-library-samples.github.io/advertising-marketing/using-google-tag-manager-for-server-side-website-analytics-on-aws.html

First, I deployed this architecture within the eu-central-1 region. I was able to see logs for the ECS Services with this setup. The roles **execution_role_arn** and **task_role_arn** were also created initially within the eu-central-1 region repo and everything seemed to work well.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "PrimaryServerSideContainer" {
  family                   = "PrimaryServerSideContainer"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = 2048
  memory                   = 4096
  execution_role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::133:role/gtm_container_exec_role"
  task_role_arn            = "arn:aws:iam::133:role/gtm_container_role"
  runtime_platform {
    operating_system_family = "LINUX"
    cpu_architecture        = "X86_64"
  }
  container_definitions = <<TASK_DEFINITION
  [
  {
    "name": "primary",
    "image": "gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image",
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "PORT",
        "value": "80"
      },
      {
        "name": "PREVIEW_SERVER_URL",
        "value": "${var.PREVIEW_SERVER_URL}"
      },
      {
        "name": "CONTAINER_CONFIG",
        "value": "${var.CONTAINER_CONFIG}"
      }
    ],
    "cpu": 2048,
    "memory": 4096,
    "essential": true,
    "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "options": {
            "awslogs-group": "gtm-primary",
            "awslogs-create-group": "true",
            "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
          }
        },
    "portMappings" : [
        {
          "containerPort" : 80,
          "hostPort"      : 80
        }
      ]
  }
]
TASK_DEFINITION
}
```

However, now I am recreating the same architecture within another region (eu-west-2) while re-using the existing IAM roles. The GTM architecture works fine but the log groups are not created.

I have already changed this part:

```
    "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "options": {
            "awslogs-group": "gtm-primary",
            "awslogs-create-group": "true",
            "awslogs-region": "eu-west-2",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
          }
        },
```

Details of IAM Roles:

**gtm_container_exec_role:**

- AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
- CloudWatchLogsFullAccess

**gtm_container_role**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I do see these logs:

/aws/ecs/containerinsights/gtm/performance

but not the logs from ECS services. How come I am able to see logs in one region but not the other when everything else is the same?

Comment: can you also share the policy in IAM for both roles?

Comment: I have explained above @brushtakopo

Answer (score 1):

Please check the region in which FARGATE task is running. It should be available in details pane or you can use

```
aws ecs describe-services --cluster my_cluster --services my_service
```

and check that the region is eu-west-2.

Your IAM perimssions are correct, but double check that they have propagated and are applied.

Edit: If your FARGATE service is in region xyz, you cannot change it. You have to create a new service.

Comment: Is it possible to check this via UI? I'm logged into the eu-west-2 one and this is where i see all my ecs task definitions and services so i am hoping fargate is running here. I do however have services of the SAME name in another region (eu-central) as well

Comment: @x89 Not really, Fargate seems to have really scarce documentation regarding this. Easy way to figure this would be to go to:

ECS>
Clusters >
your-cluster >
Services >
your-service >
Tasks >
task-hash.

Then, click on the subnet ID displayed in Configuration section. This should take you to the subnet (and VPC) of your Fargate task. Check for Availability Zone under Details section. It should be one of the AZs of your region.

You can also use Cloudshell (bottom of UI) for executing aws-cli commands, so no local setup is required and you will get detailed info of your task.

Comment: Just double checked. The availability zone is eu-west-2b. So, not central.

Comment: but anyways, I force updated the services and now I am able to see the logs. There's still this problem though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646891/refresh-gtm-server-side-after-updating-container-config?noredirect=1#comment136889909_77646891

Comment: @x89 this is expected. In order to immediately see your changes to the configuration, you should force deploy. You did not see logs because the changes were not applied.

[More on that on AWS docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateService.html#ECS-UpdateService-request-forceNewDeployment:~:text=Required%3A%20No-,forceNewDeployment,-Determines%20whether%20to)